# Dynamically change DIV class for iframe based on selection jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

So I have a drop-down menu:

```
 <select id="mySelect">
  <option value="" disabled selected> Select a Report</option>
  <option value="https:report1">Report1</option>
  <option value="https:report2">Report2</option>
</select>
```

...and iframe div, which by default prior to any selection from the dropdown has the display set to none.

```
<div>
  <iframe style="display:none" id="myiframe"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="900" height="600"></iframe>
</div>
```

The value of the drop-down menu is passed to a jquery function that updates the iframe.

```
    // SELECT MENU
  $("#mySelect").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    //TAG
    console.log(value);
    $("#myiframe").attr({'src':value,'style':''});
  })
```

When a report is selected from the drop-down I need the iframe to be displayed within a formatted div class.

```
.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 30%;
  position: relative;
}
```

I imagine it is something simple, but is there a way I can add in the flexibility of applying a class ONLY when a value from the drop-down has been selected?

Thanks

Comment: Change the `div` class or change `iframe`?

Comment: @jishansiddique    Change the div class.   So the jquery is already changing the iframe based on the selection.   But I need a solution that sets the div class to  ".iframe-container"  when a selection is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can check change class based on `drop-down` selection.

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#jsChangeClass").attr('class',value);
    //TAG
    console.log(value);
    $("#msg").html(value);
    $("#myiframe").attr({'src':value,'style':''});
    alert("Change div class -> "+$("#jsChangeClass").attr('class'));
  })
```

```css
.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 30%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="" disabled selected> Select a Report</option>
  <option value="https:report1">Report1</option>
  <option value="https:report2">Report2</option>
</select>
<span id="msg"></span>
<div id="jsChangeClass" class="">
  <iframe style="display:none" id="myiframe"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="900" height="600"></iframe>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks...I don't think I explained very well, but I need a way that sets the iframe's div class to ".iframe-container" when a selection is made from the drop-down.

Comment: So, the above example helping your query or not?

Comment: Yeah it's helped thanks.  Not exactly what I was looking for but pointed me in right direction